# Some changes in stackoverflow like notice message at top?

Tags: jquery, message, css

I am following this tutorial to show messages at top of browser window.

[jQuery Notification Message like StackOverflow](http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/10/jquery-notification-message-like-stackoverflow/)

**CSS:**

```
#message {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:105;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:100%;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:#8E1609;
}

#message span {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    float:left;
}
```

**Problem:**

But problem is that it is shown above the page content at top and my website menu goes hidden behind it.

**I want** it to appear at top of the webpage content and when user close it then page content should move up. It should not also move when user scroll browser page. Just like stackoverflow.com.

How can I achieve this

Thanks

Comment: what should I use then ?

Comment: From what I can see, you need default position. Try to cut this line and maybe it'll work :-)

Comment: When I use `position: relative` then position problem is solved but it starts moving with scrolling..

Comment: You didn't say you didn't want it to scroll! (edit) Originally ;)

Comment: Yes. I don't want it to scroll but it is scrolling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the `<div>` at the top of your `<body>` and use `position: static`. This is the default, so if you just leave `position` out, it will work as well.

---

To also allow it to scroll, use [Grim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679608/990877). Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/sECk9/1/

You can create the placeholder programmatically, so it has the exact same height as the notice message:

```
var placeholder = $('<div />').css('height', $('#notification').outerHeight());
```

When removing the notification, you can remove the placeholder after the animation has finished by doing this:

```
$('#notification').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    placeholder.remove();
});
```

Comment: `<div>` is already at top in `<body></body>`. After using `position: static`, position problem is solved and message is shown above the content but when I scroll webpage, it is also moving.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `position:fixed` so the message is still there if you scroll down, add another (empty) div of the same height at the top of your page but don't position it.
Your fixed div will sit on top of it when the page is scrolled up, and move when you scroll down.

Comment: But when I close this message then body content should move up to fill the space at top..

Answer (score 1):

if you position your message with `position:fixed` then you change the normal flow. Just position it above the menu in your html and when user click the hide button the menu will take its place.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vNpeG/

Comment: your example is working but it is not working in my case. may be there is some complexity in my existing css..

Comment: @Awan to provide you a solution for your case, I need your current html code also. A jsfiddle demo like the above, with your code, would help.